# issue in jenkins master slave creation using windows service

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created one slave in windows and one in Unix using windows service and Unix ssh service.When I copy a file from master to slave using copy to slave plugin, it works in Unix.But if I do the same on windows, the file is copied in the master itself.I have given the output below. The directory it shows is in the master not in slave machine.

Building remotely on slave1 in workspace c:\jenkins\slaves\workspace\python
[copy-to-slave] Copying 'b.java', excluding nothing, from 'file:/C:/Users/Administrator/.jenkins/userContent/' 
on the master to 'file:/c:/jenkins/slaves/workspace/python/' on 'slave1'.

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot here to go off of, but try using a relative path for the destination.  Something like %WORKSPACE%/python might explain your problem.